# Получение результата в глобальную переменную (promise angular)

Tags: angularjs, promise

Не могу никак решить вопрос с глобальными переменными и promise angular.
У меня есть функция которая получается имя пользователя и возвращает его id.

```
utilsService.getUserIdByName = function (userName) {
    var def = $q.defer();
    console.log('zashol');
    console.log(userName);
    function CallClientOM() {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var website = clientContext.get_web();
    var currentUser = website.ensureUser(userName);
    clientContext.load(website);
    clientContext.load(currentUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);

        function onRequestSucceeded() {
        var userid = currentUser.get_id();
        def.resolve(userid);
        }

        function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
        //error handling
        console.log("error" + args.get_message());
         def.reject('fail');
        }
    }
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
            CallClientOM();
        });
    return def.promise;
    };
```

И есть функция в которой я вызываю её и хочу получить обратно id и записать в переменную:

```
$scope.validateRemoval = function (tag) {

    if(!$scope.showfioinitiator)
    {   
        var tagUserId = utilsService.getUserIdByName(tag.account);
        var initUserId = utilsService.getUserIdByName($scope.initdata);
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

В переменных `tagUserId` и `initUserId` таким вариантом храниться объект ответа `promise`, а не сам `id`.

Пробовал такой вариант (Способ 2 - обещания ("промизы", promises)) из статьи [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0):

```
$scope.validateRemoval = function (tag) {

    if(!$scope.showfioinitiator)
    {
        var tagUserId;
        var initUserId;
        utilsService.getUserIdByName(userName).then(function(id){
            tagUserId = id;
            console.log(tagUserId);//МОГУ ПОЛУЧИТЬ id
        });
        utilsService.getUserIdByName(userName).then(function(id){
            initUserId = id;
            console.log(initUserId);//МОГУ ПОЛУЧИТЬ id
        });

        console.log(tagUserId);//НЕ МОГУ ПОЛУЧИТЬ id
        console.log(initUserId);//НЕ МОГУ ПОЛУЧИТЬ id
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Этот вариант работает нормально и возвращает мне id, но только если я работаю с  `tagUserId` и `initUserId` внутри функции. За приделами

```
utilsService.getUserIdByName(userName).then(function(id){
    initUserId = id;
    console.log(initUserId);
});`
```

Я не могу получить никак `initUserId` и `tagUserId`

Comment: Немного не то. У меня уже используется один из методов.

Comment: Именно то, там вроде говорится, что по другому никак, пока не добавят `async`/`await`

Comment: Помогите модернизировать это. Я уже использую второй вариант "Способ 2 - обещания ("промизы", promises)". Может у меня ошибка я прочитал это уже три раза.

Comment: _Этот вариант работает нормально и возвращает мне id, но **только** если я работаю **внутри функции**_ - именно об этом и говорит этот способ. **Нельзя** никак получить значения до того как функция выполнится. Так как функция асинхронная - ты не знаешь когда она выполнится. `then` как раз позволят писать код который выполнится только тогда, когда функция вернет значение. Более удобную запись может добавить использование async/await - про них во втором ответе есть. Их пока не добавили в стандарт и не реализовали в браузерах, но можно использовать транспилер  [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/repl/)

Comment: Да я это понял. Просто я думал что можно сделать что-то типа такого
`var result = utilsService.getUserIdByName(userName).then(function(id){
        initUserId = id;
    return  initUserId;
        });`

Comment: Пока нельзя. Об этом кстати есть в ответах по ссылке, поэтому я думаю это все-таки полный дубликат того вопроса